# Why do google snippets change depending on on searching the contraction of my full company name?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing

Been really struggling at how to word this. I'm a beginner in SEO and Website content. 
My employer Melbourne Satellites actively uses the contraction Melbsat in marketing material as customers found it easier to remember and type. 
I have edited the meta descriptions for showing pages on google and the correct content appears when 'Melbourne Satellites' is searched. However, when 'Melbsat' is searched the meta descriptions do not show correctly.

Any advice?

Comment: Meta tags have very little to do with SEO anymore.  What about using the phrase "melbsat" in your content as much as is reasonable,and including it in your Google Business listing?

Comment: Do you use the contraction "melbsat" in your meta description?